# Apache Tiles combination with Spring MVC for REST ful Services, Form validation, and Sessions support

Tags: rest, spring-mvc, apache-tiles, hibernate-session, formvalidation-plugin

Whether Apache Tiles combination is suitable to work with Spring MVC, and Hibernate for REST full Services, Form validation, and Hibernate-Session support.

Any other alternative for Apache Tiles?

Comment: I think what you're asking is if you can use Spring MVC and Hibernate with Tiles. Yes.

Comment: You are right in taking the question.